# Only changing the logo of special plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

When I set the logo of my plugin in a below way, the logo of `eclipse` in all other windows are also changed. I would like to change only the logo of my tool, not other windows of `eclipse`.

```
dialog = new WizardDialog(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), wizard);
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("MyPlugin");
URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("icon/MyLogo.png"), null);
ImageDescriptor desc = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);
Image image = desc.createImage();
dialog.setDefaultImage(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have found `setDefaultImage` sets the default image used for all windows.

Instead create your own wizard dialog class extending `WizardDialog` and override the `configureShell` method. Call the `Shell.setImage` method:

```
@Override
protected void configureShell(Shell shell) {
  super.configureShell(shell);

  shell.setImage(your image);
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. However, I have currently extended "Wizard" class. In this case, what shall I do?

Comment: If you have a question please ask a question. Comments are not for questions and answers.

Comment: I have asked my question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55878345/changing-the-logo-of-wizards-of-special-plugin