# changing the logo of wizards of special plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

When I set the logo for my java plugin, the logo of other windows of `eclipse` are changed.

I have a class which extends `Wizard` and implements `IObjectActionDelegate`. Then, I have override the `run` function and write the below code in it.

```
wizard = new StartWizard();
dialog = new WizardDialog(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), wizard);
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("Plugin");
URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("icon/Logo.png"), null);
ImageDescriptor desc = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);
Image image = desc.createImage();
WizardDialog.setDefaultImage(image);
```

I have read the solution set forth to the similar post on [Only changing the logo of special plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48165110/only-changing-the-logo-of-special-plugin/48165343?noredirect=1#comment98415515_48165343). The problem is that I have extended `Wizard` and cannot extend `WizardDialog` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating `WizardDialog` yourself you can actually extend that class if you want.

In a `Wizard` you can get the current `Shell` by calling:

```
Shell shell = getContainer().getShell();

shell.setImage(your image);
```

It looks like the wizard `addPages` method would be suitable for this code.